# Mapping one Gamepad Button to press a Key Combination

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, raspbian

As part of a small project, we need the option of pressing a button on a gamepad be recognized like a keyboard shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

We first tried to solve the problem with "qJoypad", but did not succeed, as from our understanding it's not possible to enter multiple keys for one button.

Somebody got a hint?

Comment: Welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site. Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on how to best use this site. Could you please edit your post to include what you tried and what did not work specifically? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `xev` first to see if the keys are being detected?

Comment: The Mapping works fine as long as there is a 1:1 binding from one Button to one Key of the Keyboard